# checking to see if location in scene is occupied by sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building my first iPhone game using Xcode, SpriteKit and Swift.  I am new to these technologies but I am familiar with general programming concepts.

Here is what I am trying to do in English.  I want circles to randomly appear on the screen and then begin to expand in size.  However, I do not want a circle to appear in a location where a circle currently exists.  I am having trouble determining each circle's position.

Inside GameScene.swift I have the following code inside the didMoveToView:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addCircle), SKAction.waitForDuration(3, withRange: 2)]
        )))
```

The piece of code above calls my "addCircle" method:

```
func addCircle() {

    // Create sprite.
    let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grad640x640_circle")
    circle.name = "circle"
    circle.xScale = 0.1
    circle.yScale = 0.1

    // Determine where to position the circle.
    let posX = random(min: 50, max: 270)
    let posY = random(min: 50, max: 518)

    // ***Check to see if position is currently occupied by another circle here.


    circle.position = CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY)

    // Add circle to the scene.
    addChild(circle)

    // Expand the circle.
    let expand = SKAction.scaleBy(2, duration: 0.5)
    circle.runAction(expand)

}
```

The random function above just chooses a random number within the given range.  How can I check to see if my random functions are generating a location that is currently occupied by another circle?

I was thinking of using a do..while loop to randomly generate a set of x and y coordinates and then check to see if a circle is at that location but I cannot find how to check for that condition.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few methods which can help you in this regard:

1. `(BOOL) intersectsNode: (SKNode*)node`, available with SKNode, and
2. `CGRectContainsPoint()` as well as the `CGRectContainsRect()` methods.

For instance the loop to check for intersection can look as follows:

```
var point: CGPoint
var exit:Bool = false

while (!exit) {
    let posX = random(min: 50, max: 270)
    let posY = random(min: 50, max: 518)

    point = CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY)

    var pointFound: Bool = true

    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("circle", usingBlock: {
        node, stop in

        let sprite:SKSpriteNode = node as SKSpriteNode
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.frame, point))
        {
            pointFound = false
            stop.memory = true
        }
    })

    if (pointFound)
    {
        exit = true
    }
}

//point contains CGPoint where no other circle exists
//Declare new circle at point
```

Comment: You should exit out of the `enumerateChildNodesWithName` when the `if` condition is `true`. You can do that by setting `stop.memory = true`

Comment: Thanks again @0x141E. I tried setting `stop = true` but it said `cannot assign to 'let' value 'stop'`. Editing the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response!  The enumerateChildNodeswithName method was exactly what I needed.  I had a feeling something like this was available but couldn't find it.  That's why I gave each sprite the name "circle".  Thanks again.